# Identifying the field which is being duplicated!

Tags: php, mysql, unique, duplicates

I have this registration form which has several Unique fields. Now on insertion, I want to detect all the fields on which the duplicate values were tried. How can I do that? I am using MySQL server 5.5.8 and PHP 5.3. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean duplicate values in the form that was submitted, or duplicates of data already in your database?

Comment: The duplicate values already there in the db @Michael

Answer (score 0):

1. submit the form
2. query the db to see if any of those fields values are in use
3. ???
4. profit

Comment: @Marc I am looking for a solution that leads to minimum db overhead. So is there any value regarding the cardinality of the field that the MySQL returns anyhow? Using `mysqli_error()`, it returns the constraint name like `Duplicate entry 'nagi' for key 'eo_username_UNIQUE`

Comment: @6nagi9, the solution with the least overhead is probably the one with the least queries; because of that, I'd say the best is to catch any database error triggered.

Comment: Unless you want to pull out all the keys and do the search in PHP, then just do a quick query and see if they're in the DB. That or just try to insert and see if it fails. Either way, you're hitting the DB. a simple "select count(*) where ..." is pretty minimal.

Comment: @zneak So guess I need to parse that `eo_username_UNIQUE` above. Is that the only way?? Doesn't MySQL returns the **Key Position**?? coz If it doesn't, I would be better off doing what @Mark says.

Comment: Why do you need to know the key position? If you've got a unique key violation, then whatever fields are part of that key are all duplicates of some other record.

Comment: @6nagi9, the constraint names are quite fixed, so if MySQL tells you there's a duplicate for key _key_, you can simply make an array mapping constraint names to form field names (for instance, it would contain `"eo_username_UNIQUE" => "username"`) and a regex to find the constraint name from the error message (which would be like `/Duplicate entry '.*' for key '(.+)'/`).

Comment: I got that @zneak. This mapping is pretty much what I need. Thanks. And there is one more doubt. Suppose on three fields the user is entering duplicate values, now whether MySQL returns an error for the first violation only or for all three of them. And if it does for all three, how? as an array?

Comment: @6nagi9, it'll throw about one duplicate at a time. If you want to list them all at once, you will have to query for them individually. You decide if that's too expensive for you (but off my head, I'd say it actually isn't that bad).

Comment: Thanks! :) Implementing the multiple query solution eventually. Don't want to test user's patience.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify any keys that cannot have duplicates when you create the table (or afterwards with the alter table command) as unique using unique key constraints, the insert will fail. This will cause mysql_query() to return false, and you can get the error message from the previous mysql operation using myqsl_error(). Something like this:

```
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('1','2','3'))
{
    //success code
}
else
{
    $error_string = mysql_error();
    //handle error
}
```

I'm not sure that the error message will give you exactly what you are looking for, but at least it keeps your db overhead down.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL error will return only one of the keys that was violidated. As the different column values can be found in different rows, there is no easy way to get all of them. Using query like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1=val1 OR column2=val2` won't work, since it can use any indexes. Making few separate queries to check for each of the field is better approach. If this is InnoDB and you are quering only for the column (SELECT column FROM table WHERE column=val) this would be index-covered query, which is extremly fast, even if you have millions of users (and I assume we are talking about few unique fields)

Comment: I have already implemented this approach though my db is MyISAM. I've got three unique fields.

Answer (score -1):

You can loop over $_POST or $_GET, depending on whatever form method you are using.
Consider this example:

```
$input = array();

foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
  $input["$key"] = trim($val);
}
```

Now we have a sanitized version of input, trimming out leading and trailing spaces.

You get which fields were duplicated by looping over values:

```
foreach($input as $key => $val) {
  $keys = array_keys($input, $val);
  if(count($keys) > 1) {
    /* More code here */
  }
}
```

Comment: trimming values is not sanitizing input. And if you want to check if a value is presented more than once in an array, you can simply use array_count_values. However this has nothing to do with the question. It's not wise to load the whole table in an array, and the question is about multiple columns.

Comment: That is one way to do it, but it doesn't help you discover which fields were duplicated. Moreover, if it is a database question, why the hell OP has tagged it in php? I found it in unanswered php questions. :-\

Comment: You misinterpreted the question @Nilesh.